# How can I redirect on a url after successful registration?

Tags: wp-login-form, user-registration

I am a newbie to Wordpress. I am currently working on registration and login. I have a page restrict url let `http://xyz.com/abc`. Login/registration is required for this url.

I need that when a user register or login then it should be redirected on this previous url.

In login I have added the following hook :

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10);

function redirect_previous_page(){

    global $user;
    $request = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

    if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'administrator') ) ) {

        return admin_url();
        return $redirect_to;

    } elseif ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'subscriber') ) ) {

        return $request;
        return $redirect_to;

    } 

}
```

It is working for me, but I am not getting how can I redirect on this url after successful registration. I have registration link on the login page

Comment: You can't have two `return` one after the other. Your functions ends on the first `return` it meets. You also need arguments in your function. Read [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) for an example.

Comment: @RRikesh then is it possible that I can send the value of that url along with the register url, and if then how, I am using theme-my-plugin ...

Answer (score 1):

You used `in_array` wrong. There might be some redundancy in your function too(depending on what you're doing). You could use something like this to redirect your users:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10);

function redirect_previous_page(){
    global $user;
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
        return admin_url();
    } else {
        return 'http://localhost/'; //add your link here
    } 
}
```